# Dynamically comparing elements of the array

Tags: javascript

Can someone please tell me how to compare elements in array with every other element. I mean in array `arr = [a,b,c,d];`, I would like to compare `a` with `b,c,d` , `b` with `a,c,d,` etc. And to do that dynamically, no mather of the size of the array.

Comment: You can use loops for this, you could start with looking at the `for` loop.

Comment: go on http://jsfiddle.net/ an try something yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a=["a","b","c","d"];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<a.length;j++){
        if(i!=j && a[j]===a[i]){
        //match, do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if I do this

`var a=["a","b","a","d"];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
 for(var j=0;j<a.length;j++){
  if(a[j]===a[i]){
        console.log(a[i]);
      }
    }
  }`

I'm getting `a b a a d `, and I'm suppouse to get only `a` because it is only one matching

Comment: Much better now, getting the hang of it -).